# Cant match local token to passed GoCardless token

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.3 with the GoCardless API and I'm trying to build out the endpoints so my application can handle events accordingly.

I'm reading the GoCardless documentation and it says do the following:

```
$token = getenv("GC_WEBHOOK_SECRET");

$raw_payload = file_get_contents('php://input');

$headers = getallheaders();
$provided_signature = $headers["Webhook-Signature"];

$calculated_signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $raw_payload, $token);

if ($provided_signature == $calculated_signature) {

} else {

};
```

I've converted the above into Laravel friendly controller speak.

```
public function hook(Request $request)
    {

        $token = env("GC_WEBHOOK_SECRET");

        $raw_payload = $request;

        $provided_signature = $request->header('Webhook-Signature');
        $calculated_signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $raw_payload, $token);

        if ($provided_signature == $calculated_signature) {
            Log::info('It was a match!');
        } else {
            Log::info('Something went wrong!');
        };


    }
```

but I can't get the $provided_signature to match the $calculated_signature, I've got a feeling it's something to do with the way I'm hashing the token from my env file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it guys, all I needed to do was replace

```
$raw_payload = $request;
```

with

```
$raw_payload = $request->getContent();
```

Comment: hey can you help me out! i'm having 419 Authentication Timeout

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed have you checked which API your hitting? the sandbox api has it's own credentials and endpoints.

Comment: Dev.Wol i solved it. I wasn't excluding the route from VerifyCsrfToken middleware.